# Gradle configuration with multi-module android library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar

**Back history**

I have this android library `aar` that devs can use normally with

```
compile 'com.companyname.sdk:android-sdk:2.x'
```

and now we're doing a re-write of the library from scratch to create V3.

On this re-organization we managed to break the lib into modules. So one could say that on V3 we would have the following artifacts

```
compile 'com.companyname.sdk:core:3.x'
compile 'com.companyname.sdk:extra_1:3.x'
compile 'com.companyname.sdk:extra_2:3.x'
compile 'com.companyname.sdk:extra_ ....
```

and this would give on the gradle structure the following modules:

```
root:
  |- test_app (apk just for testing, not deployed anywhere)
  |- sdk (aka: core)
  |- extra_1
  |- extra_2
  |- extra_ ... etc
```

for each `extra` module on their `build.gradle` there's a `provided (':sdk')` so that can use everything from the `sdk` module, but do not actually compile it inside themselves.

but I would like to also provide a easy migration path for existing host apps. Meaning, I would like on V3 to also have the following artifact that combines `core` and `extra_1` (which it's basically what's currently on V2).

```
compile 'com.companyname.sdk:android-sdk:3.0.0'
```

That all sounds great on theory but I'm having a really hard time figuring it out a gradle structure to allow me to easily export all those.

**What I want to achieve**

So I would like to be able to during a build generate the following artifacts:

- `android-sdk` that includes both `core` and `extra_1`
- `core`
- `extra_1`
- ... all other extras

**What have I tried**

- add an extra module named `legacy`, apply `com.android.library` without any code and add `compile project` for both other modules. It generates an empty `aar`
- add core/legacy buildTypes with the sourceSets from both modules. Never generated 2 `aar`
- add core/legacy productFlavours with sourceSets from both modules. Doesn't compile because it can't find the imports from `sdk` that are declared into `extra_1` (some of which are generated during annotation processor, or lombok)
- add core/legacy productFlavours with `compile project('extra_1')`. Doesn't compile because there's a cyclic dependency between sdk and extra_1.

**Answer**

Based on Gabrielle answer I ended up digging more and found that the option to create an extra module with the dependencies is the right one. It will generate an AAR with empty manifest and empty classes. But the important part is the POM file that it will generate that will include the right dependencies.

A caveat on the approach is on the configuration for the `maven-publish` plugin. Normally you need a `publishing` object with `publications` and a `pom.withXml` node. mine was like following:

```
   pom.withXml {
                def root = asNode()
                def license = root.appendNode('licenses').appendNode('license')
                license.appendNode('name', 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0')
                license.appendNode('url', 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt')
                license.appendNode('distribution', 'repo')
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.version)
                }
            }
```

The issue with that approach is that `dependency.version` (at the end) is unspecified, and as such it generates a POM file with `<version>unspecified</version>`.

The solution there is simple thou, replace the late with some variable u have on the script with the right version number. Mine looked like:

```
dependencyNode.appendNode('version', "${rootProject.ext.SDK_VERSION}")
```

Comment: I know it is an old post but I am kinda stuck with a problem similar to yours. Can you help me with this one? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260289/merge-multiple-library-modules-into-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
root:
  |- test_app (apk just for testing, not deployed anywhere)
  |- core 
  |- extra_1
  |- extra_2
  |- extra_ ... etc
  |- android-sdk
```

In `core/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
//...
```

In `extra1/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
//...
dependencies {
   compile project(':core')
}
```

In `android-sdk/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
//...
dependencies {
   compile project(':core')
   compile project(':extra')
}
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I had tested this before and discarded because it was generating an AAR with empty classes and empty manifest. But with your input I ended up digging more and figure out that all it needs to generate is the POM file properly setting up the dependencies. I'll edit my question with a couple of caveats I found about it.

Comment: Instead of `compile project`, use `implementation project`.
When module `B` depends on module `C` with the `compile` keyword and `A` depends on `B`, `A` also depends on `C`. If we replace `compile` with `implementation`, `A` no longer depends on `C`.