# Gradle library with multiple modules

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-library

I have a gradle (Android) library with multiple modules, and some modules depends on others (very similar to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41761846/906362)

```
root/
  |- module1 -> (no dependncy)
  |- module2 -> compile project(':module1')
  |- module3 -> (no dependncy)
  |- module4 -> compile project(':module1') compile project(':module3')
  |- etc...
```

That works fine for development, as I can make changes on any module and see them reflected on the others.
But to publish builds to `jcenter()`, I need the dependencies to be their online version. Something like this:

```
root/
  |- module1 -> (no dependncy)
  |- module2 -> compile '<group>:modules1:<version>'
  |- module3 -> (no dependncy)
  |- module4 -> compile '<group>:modules1:<version>' compile '<group>:modules3:<version>'
  |- etc...
```

so that when it get added to a project, it properly references the versions found on `jcenter()` instead of the UNSPECIFIED dependency that gets added when using `compile project(':module1')`.

Currently I've published to my local maven copy, changed the dependencies to use the numbered version and then publish to jcenter(). But that is a lot of manual work that will not work on CI.

**Question:**

How do I make this work in a saner way?

I mean, how do I code/debug using what's on my local machine, but generate the POM using proper `group:module:version`.

**Edit:** To add a bit more of information:

I'm using this script here https://github.com/sensorberg-dev/gradle-bintray-push/blob/master/gradle-bintray-push.gradle
to generate dependencies and upload.

Currently dependencies that are `compile project` get generated like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>_name of the project_</groupId>
  <artifactId>_name of the module_</artifactId>
  <version>unspecified</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and I need those to be generated with the actual groupId and artifactId of the project.

Comment: you can use `SNAPSHOT` version to refers to latest commit of module https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io

Comment: But then I don't see how this would be better, as I would have to commit, push to github, wait for the build, and change the gradle modules to this version. And then the dependencies would be linked against snapshot. The issue is not to publish, but how can I code/debug using what's on my local machine and when I run `./gradle clean build uploadArchives` to build dependencies POM based on `group:module:version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `compile project(':module1')` for module2 build.gradle file.

Run `./gradlew clean -Pgroup=GROUPNAME -Pversion=VERSION uploadArchives` (or set these params via gradle.properties)

If you use JitPack, it do this automatically

Comment: Thanks! That was spot-on. After it worked from the command line I've ended up adding inside the `allProjects` tag. Like this https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/pull/6/files This will run on our own CI instance and goes to `jcenter()`