# Merge multiple library modules into one

Tags: android, maven, gradle, sdk

I am trying to merge multiple modules of my android library into one single block of implementation. e.g.

I have 3 modules which when uploaded to Maven gives 3 implementation blocks:

```
implementation 'com.example.sdk:core:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.example.sdk:feature1:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.example.sdk:feature2:1.0.2'
```

but I also want to merge them into a single maven publish as:

```
implementation 'com.example.sdk:android-sdk:1.0.2'
```

So that users who want to implement all core and features modules can implement using a single implementation line instead of multiple. Can this be possible?

I am using these classpaths in my main project:

```
classpath 'com.vanniktech:gradle-maven-publish-plugin:0.18.0'
classpath 'org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:1.4.10.2'
```

Inside every library module adding a new gradle.properties file and adding the following segment of code in that:

```
GROUP=com.example.sdk 
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=core 
VERSION_NAME=1.0.2 

POM_NAME=core 
POM_PACKAGING=aar 

POM_DESCRIPTION=Test for multi-module lib 
POM_INCEPTION_YEAR=2021 

POM_URL=GITHUB_URL 
POM_SCM_URL= GITHUB_URL 
POM_SCM_CONNECTION= GITHUB_URL.git 
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:git@GITHUB_URL 

POM_LICENCE_NAME=The Apache Software License, Version 2.0
POM_LICENCE_URL=http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt 
POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo
```

and pushing to maven with `./gradlew publish --no-daemon --no-parallel`

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try create a file named `./folder-deps/my-core.gradle` with content bellow:

```
dependencies{
  implementation 'com.example.sdk:core:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.example.sdk:feature1:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.example.sdk:feature2:1.0.2'
}
```

In all `build.gradle` import your module from file `my-core.gradle`:

```
apply from: "$rootDir/folder-deps/my-core.gradle"
```

Comment: But this will work on my project how this will be helpful for me to publish on Maven? as I want a single maven implementation link instead of multiple.

Comment: Also edited my question to make it more clear, hope it helps know to understand my question